# Mod_rewrite rewrite URL doesn't do anything

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For some reason Apache doesn't rewrite my URL's and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I can confirm that mod_rewrite works because this works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oranges.html$ apples.html
And it shows the apples.html page.
```

I am trying to use this but it doesn't do anything!

```
Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]*$ index.php?page=$1
```

To look like this: http://example.com/search/

What could be wrong here? :o

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you *expect* to happen.

Comment: I expect to have my url: www.example.com/index.php?page=search become like this www.example.com/search

Comment: You have it backwards. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained